# Prevent redirection to home page

Tags: php

I have a php website which is under development. The website url is http://www.iarlive.in . It is hosted on net4.in . On the righthand side of the page, I have graphs which get displayed in a iframe when I click on the links. This was working a few days ago. I had checked this on 4 August 2016. Unfortunately, now when I click on some links the graph is not shown but instead it gets redirected to the home page. I have verified that this problem is not related to iframe.

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Sachin

Comment: Do you have any notices in your PHP or Server error logs? I would guess the PHP files your links are referencing no longer exist or you have an htaccess causing a redirect. You would do well to improve your question by stating what exact php file link redirects and if you have any htaccess rewrites enabled?

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned here, whether you are using a php framework or not, so on the basis of it, here i have come up with below suggestion.

Step 1, try to undo the code which you did before 4 august or the code which you tested last time on live server and was working fine.

Step 2, debug it by using the php functions like exit(); and etc on each page.

step 3, uncomment javascript files if you have header.php or footer.php files ..

Hope this helps or let me know further.

Comment: this must be common file issue or the common code issue which you have followed on all the pages [the pages which are getting redirected] ..

Comment: Actually, it is only one file which is getting called with parameters which is giving this problem. Also, I have not done any code change on this file for months. But, let me check again. Also, I am using core PHP.

Comment: ok .. check the code of that particular file by putting php's exit(); statement at the top and check whether its getting redirected or not .. if not then debug step wise by replacing this code below after few lines of code and retest and so on...

Comment: @sachinb also check whether you have added or is there any htaccess file issue or not .. make sure that as well

Comment: It seems that the file which I am calling through my program is not getting called at all. Clicking on the link takes me directly to my main page. I have created a file called x.php . I open the file iarlive.in/x.php . I then click on the link . This should open another file columnchart_1.php but on clicking the link this gets redirected to iarlive.in. Also, I will check but it seems that net4.in will not allow access to .htaccess file.

Comment: try renaming that particular file and then check
try renaming the link after you renaming that file and then check

Comment: Thanks, @Mit.agile, but, I have tried this option too.